# jose.exception.JWTError: not enough segments,

Tags: jwt, pyjwt

I want to find out how to fix this error. I'm using python-jose(Poetry) in FastAPI. (I apologize if there have mistake in my sentences, because I don't use Google Translate, to improve my English skills).
python-jose[cryptograph]

```
async def get_current_user(
    db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session), token: str = Security(oauth2_scheme)
):
try:
    payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
    payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
    token_data = Token(**payload)
except PyJWTError:
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Could not validate credentials"
    )
user = await crud_user.get(db, id=token_data.id)
if not user:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
return user
```

It's working, namely creating JWT token:

```
@router.post("/token", response_model=Token, tags=['login'])
async def login_access_token(
    db_session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session),
    form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()
):
user = await  crud_user.authenticate(db_session=db_session,
                                     email=form_data.username, password=form_data.password)
if not user:
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=404, detail="Incorret password or username"
    )
elif not await crud_user.is_active(user):
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=400, detail="Inactive user"
    )
access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)

return {
    "access_type": await create_access_token(
        data = {"user_id": user.id}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    ),
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

This is my version for creating JWT token:

```
async def create_access_token(*, data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta = None):
to_encode = data.copy()
if expires_delta:
    expire = datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
else:
    expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=15)
to_encode.update({"exp": expire, "sub": access_token_jwt_subject})
encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
return encoded_jwt
```

I'm writhing async code, written across requirements.txt with using ordinary Jose and it worked out

But using Poetry Jose didn't allow use jose, because pycripto very old for these dependencies, and I was beginning to use python-jose and received this error:

> payload = jwt.decode(token, key=key, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
> File "D:\test_fastapi\test_fastapi_2\test_fastapi_3\venv\lib\site-packages\jose\jwt.py", line 144, in decode
> raise JWTError(e)
> jose.exceptions.JWTError: Not enough segments

Looked about this problem and didn't find anything exactly about python-jose

Can you help me to fix this problem? If I need to add something, please let me know.

This code doesn't work:

```
@router.post("/current_user/login", tags=["login"], 
response_model=User)
async def get_current_user_au(get_current_user: DBUser = 
Depends(get_current_user)):

   return get_current_user
```

I have watched in docs about Python-Jose and there they are using this option:

```
jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
```

And I have a SECRET_KEY, token: str = Security(oauth2_scheme), and algorithms and can't understand what I'm doing wrong.